# IIS is throwing HTTP Error 500.0 - IsapiModule

Tags: windows, iis, weblogic12c, iis-10, isapi

I've created one VM windows 2016 on Azure and installed Weblogic 12.2.1.3 and SQLServer2016.
Deployed an ear file and can get to the application login page.

I've configured IIS with this my application to have https url. I followed everything that we usually do on our on premises servers but I'm getting a weird error. Does anybody can help me please?

[image]

Comment: Only the vendor of myapp_iisproxy can answer you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below steps to solve this issue.

1.Ensure that the path to the ISAPI DLL is correct

Open the IIS mangement console and locate the web sites and find the hanlder mapping feature.

Then you find the myapp_iisproxy handler in it and check the executable's path is right or not.

[image]

2.Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.

3.Verify permissions for the DLL. Make sure your application has the permission to access the dll file.